# What triggered this SIEGSEGV Exception type

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault

The iOS app I am developing is having this crash with many of my users (I can catch it via PLCrashReporter library). The Exception type is SIGSEGV, so I believe is an error involving memory (like acceding a deallocated variable?).

But how can I discover what triggered it? The first line in the stacktrace involving my app is line 13:

```
13  ******                              0x004a9b40 _mh_execute_header +
```

And I really can't catch what this could mean.
Is there a way to see more info, or maybe the first four/five lines can help me more than I think?

Additional information: I use massively CoreData and NSManagedObjects, so I can't check every instance if those.

```
Build Version: 2.0
Incident Identifier: 5D8AECAD-3DC6-403D-8C8A-86FCC06C7FF0
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         ****** [6112]
Path:            /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/853B3A08-D893-45CA-B223-BD4A3B0241FF/******.app/******
Identifier:      com.**.******
Version:         2
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-07-30 11:56:43 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x7176d0c2
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3408df66 objc_msgSend + 5
1   CoreData                            0x25521bad -[NSManagedObject _clearRawPropertiesWithHint:] + 284
2   CoreData                            0x25521a13 -[NSFaultHandler turnObject:intoFaultWithContext:] + 398
3   CoreData                            0x2551f517 -[NSManagedObject dealloc] + 74
4   CoreData                            0x2551ec25 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 1768
5   CoreData                            0x2551e4b3 <redacted> + 326
6   CoreFoundation                      0x257d026d <redacted> + 20
7   CoreFoundation                      0x257cd951 <redacted> + 276
8   CoreFoundation                      0x257cdd53 <redacted> + 914
9   CoreFoundation                      0x257199a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
10  CoreFoundation                      0x257197b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
11  GraphicsServices                    0x2d0c11a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
12  UIKit                               0x28eca635 UIApplicationMain + 1440
13  ******                              0x004a9b40 _mh_execute_header + 4156224
14  libdyld.dylib                       0x3464faaf <redacted> + 2

[...]
```

Comment: can you reproduce it yourself or is it just a crash report from a 3rd party reporter

Comment: Also stack traces go bottom to top so the most useful information in your case is `1   CoreData                            0x25521bad -[NSManagedObject _clearRawPropertiesWithHint:] + 284`

Comment: Unfortunatly I got no idea of how reproduce this crash. Also, I knew the stack trace goes bottom to top and that is why I asked if the first lines are saying something or not: the point is I can't understand what clearRawPropertiesWithHint is, even googlin it!

Comment: Frame 13 is not correctly symbolicated, but it will only resolve on `main.m` line `14` which is if no help. You have a memory issue somewhere in your code that can result in a crash anywhere else in the app. It is not possible to show the line of code that causes this kind of crash!